# 75% CPU wait and apt upgrade hanging

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, iowait

Recently I observed a relatively constant 7/8 (core) load on one of my servers. Looking with top, seems that CPU is constantly 75% waiting:

```
Tasks: 401 total,   1 running, 400 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 25.0 id, 74.9 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
```

Can't find anything obvious. System has 4x10TB drives out of which 4x9TB are allocated to a ZFS pool, the rest is mdadm RAID10. /proc/mdstat shows no check/rebuild, for ZFS I'm not sure exactly where to look at.

I did an `apt update ; apt upgrade` (Debian 10.7), hanged for already 30minutes at:

```
Unpacking linux-image-4.19.0-14-amd64 (4.19.171-2) ...

Progress: [ 33%] [#######################################################################................................................................................................................................................]
```

The applications seem to run fine other than that. I was thinking of a `reboot`, since it has almost 300d uptime but now with apt upgrade hanging I really don't know how to proceed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 300 days? That's far too long to let a system go without rebooting. Anyway, I/O wait is almost always disk. You should start looking there.

Comment: ZFS can get really slow if you run out of disk space.